# Passing Data between Table View in Swift

Tags: swift, tableview

I am trying to pass a data from main table view controller to detail tableview controller. i am getting lot of rows in my detail with with "label" indicated on it. I think i am doing some mistake in specifying the number of rows in a section, but not sure how to fix it. any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

this is how i passed the data from main table view to detail table view

```
import UIKit

class mainSectionViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    @IBOutlet weak var mainSectionTableView: UITableView!

    var arrayOfSections : [Sections] = [Sections]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.setupmainSections()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    func setupmainSections() {

        var EA503 = Sections (sectionHeader: "Equal Angle", sectionImage: "angle equal.gif", subSection: "50x50x5")

        var EA756 = Sections (sectionHeader: "Equal Angle", sectionImage: "angle equal.gif", subSection: "75x75x6")

        var UA50403 = Sections (sectionHeader: "Unequal Angle", sectionImage: "angle unequal.gif", subSection: "75x75x6")

        var UA90608 = Sections (sectionHeader: "Unequal Angle", sectionImage: "angle unequal.gif",subSection: "90x60x8")

        var UC10015 = Sections (sectionHeader: "Universal Column", sectionImage: "Column.gif", subSection: "UC10015")

        var UB15015 = Sections (sectionHeader: "Universal Beam", sectionImage: "beam.gif",subSection: "UB15015")

        var PFC100 = Sections (sectionHeader: "Parallel Flange Chanel", sectionImage: "PFC.gif", subSection: "PFC100")

        var CHS300 = Sections (sectionHeader: "Circular Hollow Section", sectionImage: "chs.gif", subSection: "CHS300")


        var SHS200 = Sections (sectionHeader: "Square Hollow Section", sectionImage: "shs.gif",subSection: "SHS200")

        var RHS50 = Sections (sectionHeader: "Rectangular Hollow Section", sectionImage: "rhs.gif", subSection: "RHS50")

        var EA253 = Sections (sectionHeader: "Equal Angle", sectionImage: "angle equal.gif", subSection: "25x25x3")

        arrayOfSections.append(EA503)
        arrayOfSections.append(EA756)
        arrayOfSections.append(UA50403)
        arrayOfSections.append(UA90608)
        arrayOfSections.append(UC10015)
        arrayOfSections.append(UB15015)
        arrayOfSections.append(PFC100)
        arrayOfSections.append(CHS300)
        arrayOfSections.append(SHS200)
        arrayOfSections.append(RHS50)
        arrayOfSections.append(EA253)
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let mainsection = arrayOfSections[indexPath.row]
        let subsectionViewController : detailSectionViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("detailSectionViewController") as detailSectionViewController

        subsectionViewController.headerLabelText = mainsection.sectionheader
        subsectionViewController.sectionProperties = arrayOfSections

        presentViewController(subsectionViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
     }
}
```

this is my detail table view

```
import UIKit

class detailSectionViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var headerLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var subSectionTableView: UITableView!

    var headerLabelText : String?
    var sectionProperties : [Sections] = [Sections]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.headerLabel.text = headerLabelText
        headerLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        headerLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        headerLabel.clipsToBounds = true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return sectionProperties.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let subCell : detailSectionViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("subCell") as detailSectionViewCell

        let subsection = sectionProperties[indexPath.row]

        if (subsection.sectionheader == headerLabelText) {

           subCell.setupSubCell(subsection.subsection)

        }

        return subCell
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code of the data pass and the detail view controller's data source.

Comment: Post your prepareForSegue() function from the main table view controller at minimum.

Comment: just added more detail

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies here:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return sectionProperties.count
    }
```

you have assigned:

subsectionViewController.sectionProperties = arrayOfSections

Well, the arrayOfSections has 11 members.  arrayOfSections.sectionHeader has 8 unique members (but 11 total entries).You are going to have declare a parameter that counts the number of unique sectionHeaders.

Comment: Thanks Steve, my data source defined in the main VC is bit different. I have edited my question with the data source now. I noted i have two issues. 1) main table view - displays the sectionHeader string, but need to group it based on same string 2) when I tap a cell in the main vc, i could see the filtered sections items displayed on the detail view...say string "subSection

Comment: Not sure I understand.  Can you be specific about what gets displayed incorrectly vs. what should be displayed?

Comment: if you see my data i have 11 lines of data. so I am getting 11 rows. If you look at the sectionHeader I have 8 different ones like "Equal Angle, Unequal Angle, Universal Beam, Universal Column, Parallel Face Flange,....Rectangular Hollow Section. I want to display only 8 not 11 i.e. do not want to display the same item again. When i tap the row in the main VC I am also getting 11 rows. for example i click 'Equal Angle"...I get 3 rows with value as I have 3 Equal Angle and rest 8 rows are displayed with value "label". I want only 3 appearing. Any help or suggestion would be much appreciated